how do i call c#/.net from rust?
i found 2 web articles covering this topic (https://medium.com/@chyyran/calling-c-natively-from-rust-1f92c506289d, ...), but as a rust & programming language interop newcomer, it is very hard for me to understand how interop/ffi works; chatgpt doesn't help much.
so: does anyone has working example code?
i'd like to call c# functions for interacting with yubikeys (hardware security module) from rust (i know there is a rust crate on crate.io for communication with yubikeys, but i prefer the official sdk).
 var yubiKeys = YubiKeyDevice.FindAll();
 foreach (var item in yubiKeys)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(item);
 }

how do i do this in rust without using a yubikey specific crate?
i tried to understand this article:
https://medium.com/@chyyran/calling-c-natively-from-rust-1f92c506289d

i tried chatgpt

c#
using System;

namespace MyMathLibrary
{
    public class MathFunctions
    {
        public static int Addition(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}

rust:
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::env;
use winapi::um::libloaderapi::{LoadLibraryA, GetProcAddress, FreeLibrary, HMODULE, FARPROC};
use std::ffi::CString;

type AdditionFn = extern "C" fn(i32, i32) -> i32;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let exe_path = env::current_exe().expect("path to file couldn't be found");
        let dll_path = exe_path.with_file_name("MathLibrary.dll");

        let dll_name = CString::new(dll_path.to_str().expect("invalid file path")).expect("CString creation failed");
        let dll_handle: HMODULE = LoadLibraryA(dll_name.as_ptr());
        if dll_handle.is_null() {
            panic!("DLL konnte nicht geladen werden");
        }

        let addieren_fn_name = CString::new("Addition").expect("CString creation failed");
        let addition_fn_ptr: FARPROC = GetProcAddress(dll_handle, addition_fn_name.as_ptr());
        if addition_fn_ptr.is_null() {
            panic!("function not found");
        }
        let addition_fn: AdditionnFn = std::mem::transmute(addition_fn_ptr);

        let result = addition_fn(10, 20);
        println!("result: {}", result);

        FreeLibrary(dll_handle);
    }
}



Opening and calling managed DLL from native code is quite difficult. It is easier to call native methods from C#. Read about P/Invoke.

In particular, you cannot use LoadLibrary (or any wrapper such as libloading), since it is intended for native DLLs.
